# How to get actual, specific column data types in Snowflake using SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, information-schema

I need to get column data types for multiple Snowflake tables and views, using SQL. SQL can be Snowflake-specific.

I know that this task can be accomplished by querying standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects. However, the column data types returned from such a query are generalized types like TEXT, NUMBER etc. I am trying to get actual Snowflake column data types, e.g. VARCHAR, DATETIME, SMALLINT etc.

In SQL Server, for example, this can be done by querying `sys` views. Is there an equivalent set of objects in Snowflake that can be queried? I haven’t been able to find any.

Additional constraint is that it should be a single query that returns column types for multiple tables, not one query per table or view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the COLUMNS-view (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html) doesn't provide you enough information, you can try to use `SHOW COLUMNS` to list all columns from all tables for which you have access priviliges:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-columns.html

According to the docs you can see at least presicion and scale of the data type there:

```
{"type":"FIXED","precision":38,"scale":0,"nullable":true}
```

Comment: Thanks, SHOW COLUMNS indeed returns detailed column data type info. Too bad that it lacks some kind of where clause that would allow selection of only certain schemas and/or tables. But if this is the closest approximation of the queries I am after, it is good enough.

Comment: You can use RESULT_SCAN() to process the results of SHOW COLUMN as a table: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html :)

Comment: Here is an example query to use show columns as a table `SELECT LOWER("column_name") AS column_name, 
                                LOWER(PARSE_JSON("data_type"):type::string) AS data_type
                                FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))`